# String building: Hiding string length?

Tags: python, string

I'm modifying python code and I came across this statement and have no idea what it means nor can I find anything on the interent about it. Sorry that its so out of context..

```
conn.queue.put('%x\r\n%s\r\n' % (len(chunk), chunk)
                                        if chunked else chunk)
```

The code is putting a chunk in a threaded queue to send at a later time. My question is what is going on here '%x\r\n%s\r\n' It appears its putting the string length then hiding it with a carriage return? Also Im confused what the 'if chunked else chunk does' as far as it being an if statement with no body.

Thanks

Comment: "hiding it with a carriage return"?  Don't you mean separating it into two lines using DOS-style line-ending conventions of '\r\n'?  Why do you say "hiding"?  What makes this appear "hidden" to you?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an if statement with no body, it's a conditional expression. `A if condition else B` evaluates to `A` if `condition` is true, otherwise it evaluates to `B`. So in this case:

```
'%x\r\n%s\r\n' % (len(chunk), chunk)
                                    if chunked else chunk
```

Will either be:

```
'%x\r\n%s\r\n' % (len(chunk), chunk)
```

or just `chunk`, depending on whether `chunked` is true or not. The result of that is then passed to `conn.queue.put`.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what the resulting string would be if chunked? say len(chunk) = 3 and chunk = 'abc'

Comment: @Tony: the result would be `"3\r\nabc\r\n"`, which is basically the length, a line break, the string, and then another line break. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Example for an example of how this would look in a HTTP 1.1 conversation